# Backing up Thunderbird from one laptop to another with RSync?

Tags: permissions, backup, thunderbird, rsync, chmod

I installed Ubuntu on another laptop that I want to back up to.

I run this:

```
ole@mkt:~$ rsync -vaz /home/ole/.thunderbird ole@192.168.1.21:/~
ole@192.168.1.21's password: 
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/~" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(682) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

And it apparently is not allowed to create the `.thunderbird` directory on the backup target.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly rsync does not resolve `/~`.  If I change the example to this:

```
rsync -vaz /home/ole/.thunderbird ole@192.168.1.21:/home/ole/
```

It works.

Comment: Not in the target -remote - path, but it will work in the local path.